# Openvino MFX: Unsupported extension: rtsp://cris:pass@192.167.1.175:444/live/ch0 , Ubuntu

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, ip-camera, openvino

HI I'm running python Opencv motion detection script on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS  which is working fine, after running `source /opt/intel/openvino_2021/bin/setupvars.sh`  and if I run it with OpenVINO 2021.2.185 then I got `Openvino MFX: Unsupported extension: rtsp://cris:pass@192.167.1.175:444/live/ch0` and If I change it from IP camera `src='rtsp://cris:pass@192.167.1.175:444/live/ch0'`  to  webcam  `src=0`  then everything works fine .

Can you please help me please ??

Below is the error

```
[ WARN:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1766) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: your GStreamer installation is missing a required plugin
[ WARN:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1781) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module uridecodebin0 reported: No URI handler implemented for "rtsp".
[ WARN:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (909) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (501) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
libva info: VA-API version 1.8.0
libva info: User environment variable requested driver 'iHD'
libva info: Trying to open /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_8
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
MFX: Unsupported extension: rtsp://cris:pass@192.167.1.175:444/live/ch0
[ WARN:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1601) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: cannot link elements
libva info: VA-API version 1.8.0
libva info: User environment variable requested driver 'iHD'
libva info: Trying to open /opt/intel/mediasdk/lib64/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_8
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
MFX: Unsupported FourCC: XVID (0x44495658)
[ERROR:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (561) open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.5.1-openvino) ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): video.avi in function 'icvExtractPattern'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may refer [here](https://github.com/alexa/avs-device-sdk/issues/524) to troubleshoot this[ WARN:0] global ../opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1766) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: your **GStreamer installation is missing a required plugin**

Next, for the error of Openvino MFX: Unsupported extension: rtsp://cris:pass@192.167.1.175:444/live/ch0, please refer to this [thread](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Distribution-of-OpenVINO/OpenCV-4-1-2-openvino-CAP-IMAGES-can-t-find-starting-number-in/td-p/1129111#comment-1959910)

Comment: Many thanks for the answer , the solving solution was described by the [link shared](//community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Distribution-of-OpenVINO/OpenCV-4-1-2-openvino-CAP-IMAGES-can-t-find-starting-number-in/td-p/1129111#comment-1959910) specificaly by : uninstalling the curent version :l_openvino_toolkit_p_2021.2.185 and installing older version: l_openvino_toolkit_p_2020.3.341